# Index out of range, when context.ExecuteQuery(). While creating the Taxonomy

Tags: client-object-model, taxonomy, provider-hosted-app

I am writing a provider hosted app. In this I am trying to create taxonomy group and then multiple term sets. The first set gets created successfully but the second time in the foreach loop, context.ExecuteQuery() gives error index out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that you load the term store groups first before adding to it

```
TermStore = TaxonomySession.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
context.Load(TermStore, t => t.Id, t => t.Groups, t => t.KeywordsTermSet);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```